# How do I apply a blue to yellow gradient on a bitmap through code, brightness as factor

Tags: java, c++, image-processing, colors, gradient

I need to apply a blue to yellow gradient to a bitmap.
The factor here is the brightness.
The dark areas of the photo need to be blueish and the brightest area's yellow.
So the brightness of every pixel needs to be taken as a factor.

Can someone help me how to accomplish this in c++ or java?
The input is an array of rgb integer values of the original photo.

Comment: Why the requirement for C++ or Java? This seems like the sort of thing that would be best performed by a [raster editing program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_graphics_editors).

Comment: It too use in real time image processing. So I need to adjust the frames in real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the following (applied to all pixels individually) should do what you want:

```
// max_value gives the maximum allowed value for red, green and blue; that is,
// if red, green and blue are all equal to max_value, you have full white)
change_pixel(int& red, int& green, int& blue, int max_value)
{
  blue = (red+green+blue)/3;
  red = green = (max_value-blue);
}
```

Comment: THX man!, this did the trick. Had too set max_value too 255 and multiply blue 2 times because I only go to half brightness, the other half is to go smoothly from yellow too red. This answer can be voted. I don't have enough reputation yet :).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like a homework question, but here's the general idea, or at least, how I would do it.

For each pixel, calculate the average brightness, so add `R` `G` and `B` together then divide by 3 to get the result (you'll need to use a variable greater than 8 bits here!).

Now you have a value back in the range of 0-255 indicating the brightness of the pixel (there are various ways to calculate brightness but this will do for now).

Full blue is `(0,0,255)`, full yellow is `(255,255,0)` — so you need to interpolate between these values (we'll use linear interpolation here):

If your brightness is 50 for instance, it's ~20% of 255, so you want a colour that's 80% blue and 20% yellow. You can calculate the valye for the red channel like so:

```
R = (brightness / max) * (R in Yellow - R in Blue);
```

With similar calculations for the other channels, so for our pixel with a brightness of 50 we'd do:

```
R = (50 / 255) * 255;
G = (50 / 255) * 255;
```

Of course, we can't have negative values, and using `B in Yellow - B in Blue` idea isn't going to cut it for the blue channel, you need to invert the interpolation. By taking our 0.2 and subtracting it from 1 we can work through the range 0-255 in the other direction:

```
B = (1 - (50 / 255)) * 255;
```

Extra note: To work with something like this in C++ I'd suggest using SDL, it's nice and easy this kind of thing.

Comment: It's not a homework question really :). I'm struggling at creating some thermal vision effect filter. This is what I had so far. It's with 3 colors. From Blue to Yellow and From Yellow To Red. Yellow to Red color goes smoothly but Blue to yellow doesn't :(.

Comment: @user1083398: Yellow to red changes a single color channel (G), but yellow to blue must simultaneously change all three color channels (R, G and B).